# Foreach by reference, only some array items

Tags: php, reference, foreach

I have an `$args` array. I want to to change some values in it.

The code

```
foreach( array( $args['key_to_validate'], $args['another_one'] ) as &$arg ) {
    $arg = validate($arg);
}
```

is invalid as per [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) and gives a syntax error.

So I must do:

```
$arguments_to_validate[] =& $args['key_to_validate'];
$arguments_to_validate[] =& $args['another_one'];

foreach ( $arguments_to_validate as &$arg ) {
    $arg = validate($arg);
}
```

Another way:

```
$argument_keys_to_validate = array( 'key_to_validate', 'another_one' );
foreach ( $argument_keys_to_validate as $key ) {
    $current_arg =& $args[$key];
    $current_arg = validate( $current_arg );
}
```

Is there a more elegant way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach ( array( 'key_to_validate', 'another_one' ) as $key ) {
    validate($args[$key]);
}
```

Make sure that your validate function takes argument by reference.

Comment: This looks like a great answer. I edited my original question to better show that I hadn't thought of the validation function taking a reference, I just forgot to type in `$arg = ` before `validate($arg)`

Comment: @HeikkiU, `$args[$key] =` added

Comment: Thanks, but I think your original solution was even more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Use php 5.5 and first variant would be work. :^ )